# Cygwinの端末を指定のフォルダでエクスプローラーの右クリックから開きたい

Tags: windows, cygwin

ここに書かれている通りchereでやりたいことはできました。

> chere -i -t mintty
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637601/open-cygwin-at-a-specific-folder

フォルダ名が英語ならば、エクスプローラーでフォルダを右クリックしてそのフォルダでCygwinの端末が開いてくれます。

しかし、フォルダ名が日本語だと正常動作せず、
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
が開かれてしまいます。

日本語フォルダでも正常に動作させるにはどのようにすればいいんでしょうか？

Comment: 昨日付けの cygwin `setup-x86_64.exe` で一式更新して実行してみたら当方では日本語フォルダでも正常動作しました。そちらで失敗するのであれば、おそらく文字コードの扱いの違いだと思われます。環境変数 `LANG` および `LC_ALL` の設定はどうなっているでしょうか？当方は `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8` と `LC_ALL` は無しです。

Comment: `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8`、`LC_ALL`は無しです。私の個人的な環境の問題かもしれませんが、とりあえず、下記自己回答のとおり、自分で解決できました。コメントありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

自分でさらに調べたところ、下記手順でできましたので、ご報告いたします。

①下記を「a.reg」というファイル名でWindows上のどこかに保存する。
②「C:\\pg\\cygwin64」を自分の環境のcygwinパスに合わせて編集する。
③「a.reg」をダブルクリックしてレジストリに登録する。
④エクスプローラーから日本語フォルダを右クリックして「Cygwin Here」を実行する。
⑤日本語フォルダで、minttyが起動される。

非ASCIIの場合は、minttyのオプションで「--dir」をつける必要がある旨、下記に書かれていました。
https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin64_bash]
@="Cygwin Here(&B)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin64_bash\command]
@="C:\\pg\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe --dir \"%1\" -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cygwin64_bash]
@="Cygwin Here(&B)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cygwin64_bash\command]
@="C:\\pg\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe --dir \"%1\" -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cygwin64_bash]
@="Cygwin Here(&B)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cygwin64_bash\command]
@="C:\\pg\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe --dir \"%1\" -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash"
```